# Using loopback for synchronous IPC when using NUMA architecture

Tags: linux, sockets, ipc, low-level, numa

(For a Linux platform) Is it feasible (from a performance point of view) to try to communicate (in a synchronous way) via loopback interface between processes on different NUMA nodes?

What about if the processes reside on the same NUMA node?
I know it's possible to memory bind a process and/or set CPU affinity to a node (using libnuma). I don't know if this true also for the network interface.

**Later edit.** If loopback interface is just a memory buffer used by kernel, is there a way to be sure that buffer is on the same NUMA node in order for two processes to communicate without the cross node overhead?

Comment: What kind of bandwidth / messages-per-second requirements do you have?  Are you going to have lots of threads hammering hard on this, or is it just for the occasional message like once in several millisecond or something to get a worker thread started on something and notify when finished, with the main data in shared memory if it's large?  That could be ok, but beware that system call overhead is *high*, especially on modern x86 with Meltdown / Spectre mitigation active.

Answer (score 1):

Network interfaces don't reside on a node; they're a device - virtual or real - shared across the whole machine. The loopback interface is just a memory buffer somewhere or other, and some kernel code. The code that runs to support that device is likely bouncing round the CPU cores, just like any other thread in the system.

You talk of NUMA nodes, and tagged the question with Linux. Linux doens't run on pure NUMA architectures, it runs on SMP architectures. Modern CPUs from, say, Intel, AMD, ARM all synthesise an SMP hardware environment using separate cores, varying degrees of cache / memory interface unification, and high speed serial links between cores or CPUs. Effectively it's not possible for the operating system or software running on top to see the underlying NUMA architecture; it thinks it's running on a classical SMP architecture.

Intel / AMD / everyone else have done this because, back in the day, successful multiple CPU machines *really were* SMP; they had multiple CPUs all sharing the same memory bus, and had equal access to the RAM at the other end of the bus. Software got written to take advantage of that (Linux, Windows, etc).

Then the CPU manufacturers realised that SMP architectures suck so far as speed improvements are concerned. AMD blinked first, and ditched SMP in favour of Hypertransport, and were successful. Intel persisted with pure SMP for longer, but soon gave up too and started using QPI between CPUs.

But to give the old software (Linux, Windows, etc) backward compatibility, the CPU designers had to create a synthetic SMP hardware environment on top of Hypertransport and QPI. In principal they might have, at that point in time, decided that SMP was dead and delivered us pure NUMA architectures. But that would likely have been commercial suicide; it would have taken coorindation of the entire hardware and software industries to agree to go that way, but by then it was already far too late to rewrite everything from scratch.

Thinks like network sockets (including via the loopback interface), pipes, serial ports are not synchronous. They're stream carriers, and the sender and receiver are not synchronised by the act of transferring data. That is, the sender can `write()` data and think that that has completed, but the data is in reality still stuck in some network buffer somewhere and hasn't yet made it into the `read()` that the destination process will have to call to receive the data.

What Linux will do with processes and threads is endeavour to run them all at once, up to the limit of the number of CPU cores in the machine. By and large that will result in your processes running simultaneously on separate cores. I think Linux will also use knowledge of which physical CPU's memory holds the bulk of a process's data, and will try to run the process on that CPU; memory latency will be a tiny bit better that way.

If your processes try to communicate via socket, pipe or similar, it results in data being copied out of one process's memory space into a memory buffer controlled by the kernel (that's what `write()` is doing under the hood), and then being copied out of that into the receiving process's memory space (that's what `read()` does). Where that intermediate kernel buffer actually is doesn't really matter because the transactions taking place at the microelectronic level (below the SMP level) are pretty much the same regardless. Memory allocations and processes can be bound to specific CPU cores, but you can't influence whereabouts the kernel puts its memory buffers through which the exchanged data must pass.

Regarding memory and process core affinity - it's really, really hard to do this to any measurable benefit. The OSes are so good nowadays at understanding the behaviour of CPUs that it's almost always best to simply let the OS run your processes and cores whereever it chooses. Companies like Intel make large code contributions to the Linux project, specifically to ensure that Linux does this as well as possible on the latest and greatest chips.

==EDIT==
Additions in the light of engaging comments!

By "pure NUMA" I really mean systems where one CPU core cannot directly address memory physically attached to another CPU core. Such systems include Transputers, and even the Cell processor found in the Sony PS3. These aren't SMP, there's nothing in the silicon that unifies the separate memories into a single address space, so the question of cache coherency doesn't come into it.

With Transputer systems the only way to access memory attached to another transputer was to have the application software send the data over via a serial link; what made it CSP was that the sending application would finish sending until the receiving application had read the last byte.

For the Cell processor, there were 8 maths cores each with 256kbyte of RAM. That was the only RAM the maths cores could address. To use them the application had to move data and code into that 256k of RAM, tell the core to run, and then move the results out (possibly back out to RAM, or onto another maths core).

There are some supercomputers today that aren't disimilar to this. The K machine (Riken, Kobe in Japan) has an awful lot of cores, a very complex on-chip interconnect fabric, and OpenMPI is used by applications to move data around between nodes; nodes cannot directly address memory on other nodes.

The point is that on the PS3 it was up to application software to decide what data was in what memory and when, whereas modern x86 implementations from Intel and AMD make all data in all memories (no matter if they're shared via an L3 cache or are remote at the other end of a hypertransport or QPI link) accessible from any cores (that's what SMP means afterall).

The all out performance of code written on the Cell process was truly astounding for the Watts and transistor count. Trouble was in a world where programemrs are trained in writing for SMP environments, it takes a brain transplant to get to grips with one that isn't.

Newer languages like Rust and Go have reintroduced the concept of communicating sequential processes, which is all one had with Transputers back in the 1980s, early 1990s. CSP is almost ideal for multicore systems as the hardware does not need to implement an SMP environment. In principle this saves an awful lot of silicon.

CSP implemented on top of today's cache coherent SMP chips in languages like C generally involves a thread writing data into a bufffer, and that being copied into a buffer belonging to another thread (Rust can do it a little differently because Rust knows about memory ownership, and so can transfer ownership instead of copying memory. I'm not familiar with Go - maybe it can do the same).

Looked at at the microelectronic level, copying data from one buffer to another is not really any different to what happens if the data is shared by 2 cores instead of copied (especially in AMD's hypertransport CPUs where each has its own memory system). To share data, the remote core has to use hypertransport to request data from another core's memory, and more traffic to maintain cache coherency. That's about the same amount of hypertransport traffic as if the data where copied from one core to the other, but then there's no subsequent cache coherency traffic.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure NUMA"?  Do you mean non-cache-coherent?  Yes that might have been an option, but not very good for systems with a few / several cores running a single system image.  Coherent shared memory is much more valuable.  It wasn't just x86 that went [ccNUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access#Cache_coherent_NUMA_(ccNUMA)); so did basically everything else that runs multi-threaded code.  Except for some huge clusters that basically use non-coherent shared memory as an interconnect between systems, not a single kernel running across all cores.

Comment: There are some heterogeneous ARM chips with cores that aren't cache-coherent, but we don't run a single kernel or `std::thread` across those coherency boundaries.  In real-world systems even outside of x86, cache-coherent NUMA is widespread.  We usually call it a cluster, not a single NUMA system, when shared memory isn't coherent.  At least that's my understanding.

Comment: I think it's definitely NUMA hardware (numactl --hardware shows a lot of nodes). And using numa_bind() from libnuma showed perf improvements.

Comment: @jackmalkovick: This answer is talking about formal definitions of NUMA that could include lots of things that are impossible for an x86 system.  e.g. x86 guarantees coherent shared memory (with strong ordering rules), even if different cores have different latency to access some parts of memory.  (That's NUMA).  So on a "normal" system (like I commented earlier), you always have cache-coherency and NUMA is just a matter of performance, not needing extra flushes for your stores to be visible at all to other cores.

Comment: @PeterCordes, there were some pure NUMA systems, generally a long time ago. If anyone remembers Transputers, networks of those were at the time seen as the way forward. Code running on one Transputer could not address memory on another; the application software had to move data around itself, using a CSP programming model. This has come back into fashion in languages like Go, Rust, Erlang. Also the French had an experiemental NUMA system, can't remember the name of it (Coral?), but that didn't succeed either.

Comment: @PeterCordes The irony of CSP coming back into fashion is that it has to be implemented on top of cache coherent SMP environments that Intel and friends give us, whereas in fact a CSP application doesn't need that at all. If an entire computer system were pure CSP (as opposed to shared memory), then all the transistors dedicated to maintaining cache coherency could be removed from designs, saving power / size / cost. Not going to happen though, there's too much legacy software that isn't CSP. The PS3's cell processor was a bit like this, and that was very quick indeed.

Comment: @jackmalkovick My point about it not being worthwhile trying to beat the OS is that, yes, on a particular machine you might write code that uses core affinity to get a good result. Trouble is, if you then run that code on another machine with a different number of cores / interconnect speed / memory config it might run really badly. You could write your code to adapt, but then that's what the OS is already doing. So in general, it's hardly ever worth it. Plus, if anything else is running on the machine too, fixed affinities can be a bad idea...

Comment: @PeterCordes, added some (possibly tldr!) additions.

Comment: I think most people's definition of NUMA requires a shared address-space.  It's non *uniform*, but all the memory is still accessible to all the cores.  (Including via virtual memory tricks for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory without HW shared mem, I guess: [NUMA vs. cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access#NUMA_vs._cluster_computing))  But you seem to be including systems like Cell, where if I understand correctly, software has to manage copying data into / out of its private RAM.  That's not NUMA, that's a whole separate memory.

Comment: This is all just quibbling over terminology, though.  For any given system architecture, it doesn't matter whether you classify it as NUMA or not, just how you can program it and what kind of detailed performance characteristics it has.

Comment: @PeterCordes, oh yes I certainly agree with that; it's terminolgy (and age on my part I'm afraid. I'm of a vintage where I produced systems using those things...). The term NUMA has taken on some nuances in recent decades. I do find it interesting to analyse the price we pay (in terms of silicon complexity, heat, etc) to maintain a software ecosystem that came out of SMP